# Speeding up a slow app with lots of cursor action and image loading

Tags: android, performance, image-processing, cursor

My app is running a bit too slow in one place.  The rest of the app`s 4 different activities are reasonably fast responding, however one of the activities is too slow for comfort.  From the main activity you press a button and it starts the next activity with a gridView which fills with images and text in each view.   After the button press it takes too long, like 3 to 5 seconds before that gridView loaded page appears.

Testing on an vary slow 600mhz single core processor android phone made by ZTE. One of the low cost phones used by peoples like the Kalahari Bushmen in the South African Desert.  For those that don`t know, it would be an understatement to say that it is not in the same class as a Samsung Galaxy S3 or iPhone 5.

I wonder if I can do something to the code in the slow running portion of the app to give it a kick in the ass for speed.  Any ideas?  The only thing I can see is that the extensive use of multiple cursors and query of databases that may be slowing it down.  I imagine that loading up the gridView takes up some serious jigaboo.

My code is messy, but I wonder if there is something that I can do.  How about doing all the content provider query stuff in a separate thread?  Any ideas?  This code needs an enima.

Here below is sample of the parts of the code that are slowing down the app.

```
private void init_phone_image_grid() {
        String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img,  MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE + "='" + 1 +"'",null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
       count = imagecursor.getCount();
       imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) {

                    System.gc();

                    String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE };
                    imagecursor = managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE + "='" + 1 +"'",null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                    image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    count = imagecursor.getCount();
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);



                   // String[] proj = {  };
                   // imagecursor = managedQuery(
                   //       MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,null, null, null);
                  //  image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);


                    String i = imagecursor.getString(image_column_index);
                   // terra = i;



          // opens larger pic    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
               /*   intent.putExtra("filename", i);
                    startActivity(intent); */

                    // passing bitmap image to another activiy and starting that activity
                //  textone.setText(i); (i == /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/pic06.png)
                    Intent intentBitmapStart = new Intent(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this, Editor.class);
                    intentBitmapStart.putExtra("filename", i);

                    startActivity(intentBitmapStart);

                   // Intent myIntent = new Intent(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this, Editor.class);
                   // ImageThumbnailsActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
              }
        });
  }
```

here is a section from the getview of the adapter method.

```
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
              System.gc();


              if (convertView == null) {
                  // Make up a new view
                  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
              } else {
                  // Use convertView if it is available
                  view = convertView;
              }
              PanoramioItem s = mImageManager.get(position);

              ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
              i.setImageBitmap(s.getBitmap());
              i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);

              TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
              t.setText(s.getTitle());

              t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.owner);
              t.setText(s.getOwner());
              return view;
          }


              View view;
              ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
              if (convertView == null) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_adapterview, null);
                } else {
                    // Use convertView if it is available
                view = convertView;
                }

                  //  Toast.makeText(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this, "image_column_index2: " + image_column_index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                   int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);

                   Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id);

                    String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);

                    String[] titleText = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE };

                    textcursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, titleText, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + imagePath +"'",null, null);
                   if(textcursor.moveToFirst()){

                       titleString = (String) textcursor.getString(textcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
                   textcursor.close();
                   }
                   else{
                       titleString = "";
                   }

                    BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                   Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bfo);

                 int  imageHeight = bfo.outHeight;
                 int  imageWidth = bfo.outWidth;
                 String  imageType = bfo.outMimeType;

               BitmapFactory.Options bfo2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                 int reqHeight = 50;
                 int reqWidth = 50;

                 if (imageHeight > reqHeight || imageWidth > reqWidth) {
                     if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                         bfo2.inSampleSize = Math.round((float)imageHeight / (float)reqHeight);
                     } else {
                         bfo2.inSampleSize = Math.round((float)imageWidth / (float)reqWidth);
                     }
               }  

                 Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bfo2);

                   // iv.setImageBitmap(bm2);

                 ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapterimageview);

                 i.setImageBitmap(bm2);



                 TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adaptertextview);
                 t.setText(titleString);


                 //   iv.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
                    view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(103, 103));


                    return view;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually any long running operation in Android is done in a separate thread. If you'll hold the UI thread for more than 5 seconds, your users will see an "Application not responding" dialog and will probably get angry. A nice way to execute asynchronous operations in Android is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Another nice way to organize asynchronous data loading is to use a new concept called [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). If you master these approaches you can be sure your application will be fast and responsive on any low-end device. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you,  I will check out using Loaders from now on.  I did not think of that before.

Comment: @Kevik, You're welcome. Oh, and here's another popular post, which is a bit old now, but nevertheless very helpful: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html